# how to remove something when a :before is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to close somenthing by clicking on a `:before`?

somenthing like

HTML

```
<div class="a">
 //here comes the before i'd like to click for example a fontawesome icon
 ::before
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.a:before').click(function(){
 $(this).remove();
});
```